# Getting data from list of text files following some pattern

Tags: regex, r, matlab

I guess it's not so difficult but I'm really stuck.
I have some files, named with a string of 9 numbers, like:

```
003485295.lst
005847283.lst
092348235.lst
...
```

Each file identifies a measurement station, and contains a table with two columns, `date` and `value`, separated by a space character. For example, `003485295.lst` is:

```
date value //header row here!
2014-01-03-07:00-00 2.2
2014-01-04-07:00-00 3.1
2014-01-05-07:00-00 28.6
2014-01-06-07:00-00 2.5
2014-01-14-07:00-00 5.6
...
```

Some dates are common among all files (stations), but some are not.

### What I'm looking for

I have chosen one particular date, say `2014-01-06`. I want to:

- create an empty result file, say `2014-01-06.txt`;
- cycle through all of my `*********.lst` files;
- search if station `********` took some measurement `MM.M` that day;
- add a row in my result file, following the pattern stationId-value, like `******** MM.M` (could also be `M.M`, or `MMM.M`).

So the desired output, `2014-01-06.txt`, is something like:

```
003485295 2.5 //as we read in 003485295.lst
001022903 6.4
001022905 6.6
001022907 10.3
001026202 30.6
...
```

Stations that had no value at all for that day should be excluded. I'm on Windows and have `R` and `MATLAB` in my hands, but could work with other tools as well.

Comment: What's the volume of your lst files and how much data is in each file (just probing to suggest a scalable approach)?

Comment: Not very large right now, approx. 100 lst files and no more than 200 rows for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach using R

I would go about this the following way:

1. Upload all files to a single Data Table in R using the `read.csv` function (your files are basically space-delimited CSVs so this should be relatively easy)
2. Sort the values by dates
3. Replace the dates with Factors
4. Split the data.table by the Date Factors like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327020/in-r-how-to-split-subset-a-data-frame-by-factors-in-one-column).
5. Do a for through the data.tables and dump each separately as a CSV using the `write.csv` function

### Approach using Excel

1. Upload all files via VBA using the `DIR` function (loop through files) and reading each file - link [here](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-read-file-vba/). Use the `Split` function on spaces to tokenize the strings. Dump all the data into a single Worksheet
2. Manually sort the data by the date column
3. Write a short VBA macro to dump the data to separate files using [this](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-write-file-vba/) and a piece of code like this:

   Dim fileDate as String
   Do Until currDate.Value = ""
     if fileDate <> currDate then 
       'Create new file date
       fileDate = currDate
     end if
     'Dump data to the file
     Write #fileNo, Cells(currDate.Row, 2) 
   loop

In this whole exercise remember basically that the files are `space delimited CSVs` this will help in getting the right approach to reading and writing the files.

Comment: Approached a bit differently, but I made it. I just want to point out that `write.csv` is not OK since it won't let you use `append=TRUE`. Used `write.table` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Matlab function which will accomplish this.  (It assumes you have at least Matlab R2014b, since it uses Matlab datetimes. If not, you can use datenum instead).

```
function result = getDateData(dateToLookup)
    % Get a list of all *.lst files
    d = dir('*.lst');

    result = [];
    for i=1:length(d)
        % Read in the data file using readtable.  Delimiter is space, but need
        % to skip the first line because it doesn't follow this pattern
        t = readtable(d(i).name, 'FileType', 'text', 'Delimiter', ' ', ...
            'HeaderLines', 1, 'ReadVariableNames', false);
        t.Properties.VariableNames = {'Date', 'Data'};

        % Convert the first column to datetime
        t.Date = datetime(t.Date, 'Format', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm-ss');

        % Looks like you want to lookup by date (and not consider
        % hours/minutes/seconds, so shift these to start of day)
        t.Date = dateshift(t.Date, 'start', 'day');

        % Add in the filename to the table (minus the .lst)
        t.FileName = repmat({strrep(d(i).name, '.lst', '')}, height(t), 1);

        % Append table to the result
        result = [result; t]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end

    % This is the date you're asking for
    dt = datetime(dateToLookup);

    % Find all of the matches
    matches = result(result.Date == dt, :);

    % Create a new table as the result and write it out
    result = table(matches.FileName, matches.Data, ...
        'VariableNames', {'FileName', 'Data'});
    writetable(result, 'data.txt', 'Delimiter', ' ');
end
```