# How Can I make Multiple Subsets Based On A Column

Tags: r

I am working with a very large data set and I need to make multiple subsets from the data set without having to individually code for each subset. I want to create subsets for each Boat name in the first column.
I know how to do this boat by boat but I would like to make multiple subsets at once. I included a small sample of the data frame I am working with.
I would like to have 3 subsets from this sample data, one for each the Dawn Marie, Kraig K, and Lake Lady. Thanks for the help.

```
Boat          Net  Targeted Species     Yellow Perch
Dawn Marie    37     Yellow Perch          500
Kraig K       35     Yellow Perch          400
Dawn Marie    36     Yellow Perch         1100
Dawn Marie    34     Yellow Perch         2000
Lake Lady     30     Yellow Perch          900
Dawn Marie    31     Yellow Perch         1200
Kraig K       33     Yellow Perch         1600
Dawn Marie    44     Yellow Perch          400
Lake Lady     42     Yellow Perch          800
Dawn Marie    40     Yellow Perch          500
Dawn Marie    38     Yellow Perch          600
Lake Lady     39     Yellow Perch          400
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `?split`. This will produce a list of data.frames, which is typically the recommended structure for such applications.

Comment: To see `split` in action, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327020/split-subset-a-data-frame-by-factors-in-one-column

Comment: Thank you that appears to be what I needed.

Comment: have a look at `group_by` in `dplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `split` function.

**Description**

split divides the data in the vector x into the groups defined by f. The replacement forms replace values corresponding to such a division. unsplit reverses the effect of split.

**Usage**

```
 split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...)
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html